# Any way to ignore injected arguments in a string

Tags: python, django, string

I have an issue overriding the default error message for this django form field:

```
forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        ...
        error_messages={
            'invalid_choice': _("Given user is already a member.")
        }
    )
```

Stacktrace:

```
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1052, in clean
    raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % val)
  File "/home/.../python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 160, in __mod__
    return six.text_type(self) % rhs
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I've found that it is in fact a bug here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17840.

So my question is:

Is it possible to ignore the argument injected with `self.error_messages['invalid_choice'] % val`, without having to upgrade to django trunk version (where this is already fixed)?

Something along the lines of `'invalid_choice': _("Given user %ign is already a member.")`
Any options in python for this?

Comment: Nope, there isn't, which is why Django had to change this.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
>>> class Str2(str):
    def __mod__(self, arg):
        return self


>>> Str2('hallo')
'hallo'
>>> s = Str2('hallo')
>>> s % 3
'hallo'
```

I do not know Django so there could be some issues lie testing the class of the string but that could be hooked, too.

Comment: Because the string is wrapped in a `gettext` message factory this probably won't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: If the OP were to forgo translatability then your method works.